# How can I save a file edit using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, file, offline

My project requires me to edit and save an html file without having to press browser save button but from within the page.

For example lets say there are couple of textarea fields with previously set values, If I edit the fields and press the submit button I want the new values to be saved in the html file.

Is it possible using javascript? jquery? or even html 5? but only thing is that this has to be done offline so I can not use php or other server side languages

Comment: Sorry, but that's not possible with pure javascript. It is only possible if you make an ajax request to some server side language, but in your case you can't.

Comment: How about html 5 filesystem? any hope there?

Comment: The saving of the file may happen only with user interaction. I.e. the user should click on something and choose a path.

Comment: There is filesaver https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js; it downloads automatically to the default download location, and there is downloadify  https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify it asks for the download location, is it possible to set the download location internally from the script rather than in browser? i.e is it possible to save to a desired location without each time having to select the path